# Работа с БД в C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio

Как правильно работать с БД в C#?

К примеру, как осуществить одно подключение к БД, и потом из неё получать информацию? Как осуществлять запросы к таблицам? Как обрабатывать результаты запросов? Как выводить таблицы из БД в `DataGridView`? И прочее...

В интернете много разной информации, но толком мне ничего не понятно. Объясните на пальцах, что и как делать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Советую почитать например [Работа с базами данных на языке C#. Технология АDO .NET: Учебное пособие](http://window.edu.ru/window/library?p_rid=65225)

а также [Введение в работу с базами данных](http://www.intuit.ru/department/school/cs4kids/6/1.html)

Если интересует критерий выбора технологии, можешь ознакомиться
[Какую базу данных выбрать? Самый краткий FAQ](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-30912.html), топик старый, но хоть представление иметь будешь, от себя рекомендую АDO.NET

Примеры различных коннектов и т.п. [ADO.Net](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Catalog0560__ADO.Net.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `LINQ`.

Comment: Если работать надо с DataGridView, то лучше смотреть в сторону классического ADO.Net, хотя я солидарен с использованием LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример программы, которую я когда-то писал, для ивзлечения экзаменационных билетов из базы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;//дата провайдер для работы с необходимой нам базой

namespace MdbToTxt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] questions = new string[100];

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=I:\экз\db1.mdb"))//это строка соединения с БД

            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Билеты ORDER BY [Номер билета]", conn);//Создаём SQL-запрос

                conn.Open();//открываем соединение, должно закрыться само, но хз

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();//Выполняем запрос, в данном случе на чтение

                questions[0] = reader.GetName(0) + "\t" + reader.GetName(1) + "\t" + reader.GetName(2);//здесь будут хранится именя полей таблицы

                int i = 1;
                while(reader.Read())//а здесь собственно записи полей
                {
                    questions[i] = reader[0] + "\t\t" + reader[1] + "\t\t" + reader[2];// записи я записывал в строковый массив, хотя с ними можно выполнять всё, что душе угодно
                    i++;
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllLines("Questions.txt", questions);
        }
    }
}
```

хотите знать больше => [Работа с подключенным уровнем ADO .NET в C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html#post1061537)

Answer (score 0):

Если используете Windows Application, то можно сначала использовать базовый функционал (из меню Data). Можно начать обучение с этого.